# Windows 10 will not connect to LAN/Internet via a switch

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, lan, switch

A single Windows 10 machine on our small office network will not connect to the internet or LAN when connected via a switch.  It fails to see any network activity and reports there's no connection.  This is a new(ish) PC that's worked perfectly for a month, then suddenly no longer connects.  Nothing else has changed in that time.

```
               [Router]
                  |
               [Switch]
    ______________|________________
   |         |     |     |    |    |
 [PC]       Printers      Other PC's
```

However, when connected directly to the router it works perfectly:

```
   ┌----------  [Router]
   |               |
   |            [Switch]
   |         _____|________________
   |         |     |     |    |    |
 [PC]       Printers      Other PC's
```

I've tried the following things over the last few days based on internet searches:

1. Reset the network setting using the Windows troubleshooter.  The network icon in system tray shows a connection for a few seconds, then back to no connection.  During that time a browser still cannot connect.
2. Changed the ethernet cables
3. Swapped the switch
4. Activated wi-fi in the BIOS and used that - connects perfectly but is against company rules
5. Swapped out the machine with a laptop, which works perfectly - this leads me to blame the machine
6. Tried a different switch port

I've run out of things to try (my network experience is minimal) now.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

The specifications for each machine:

1. Router - [ASUS RT-N66U](https://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/RTN66U/HelpDesk_Manual/)
2. Switch - [Netgear GS316 - Unmanaged](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/gs316.aspx?_ga=2.238927620.523894245.1606307245-1087502301.1606307245)
3. Windows PC [Intel Ethernet Controller I225-V](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/network-io/ethernet/controllers/gigabit-ethernet-controllers/i225-v.html)

Comment: Did you try the computer in another switch port?  Do other Windows computers work on the switch?

Comment: Thanks John.  Updated.

Comment: This is now a computer issue (other computers OK). Try (1) replacing / updating the Network Card driver.  (2) TCP/IP Reset:   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: I think you've solved it good Sir!  Could you please migrate the comment as an answer?  I'll monitor it for a few days then accept if we're all good.  Many thanks.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know from your tests, try both the following:

1. Reinstall/Update the Network card driver.
2. Do a TCP/IP reset, DNS Flush:

   Open `cmd.exe` with *Run as Administrator*.

   ```
    netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
    ipconfig /flushdns
   ```

   Restart the computer .

   This works for many situations.

Comment: Thank you. Some further investigation based on your answer reveals that there are many people having problems with the I225-V drivers and require firmware updates to fix

Comment: I've had issues with that model part in the past.  I recall having to install a compatible realtek driver rather than the Intel one due to some functional issues.